# Moving files from intranet to extranet - ShaerPoint 2010

Tags: development, workflow, extranet, intranet

I am working on a new SharePoint project (new to SP overall) and a requirement is to "publish" documents on the intranet, across different sites, to a desired location on an extranet.  The intranet is set up as 1 site collection with multiple sites under it.  I was told that I could use content deployment for this, but I don't see how because they are both on the same server.  I also read that there is an out of the box solution, but you can only move files within the same site collection.
  Currently I know a little C#, but am not even sure where to put custom code.  Is there a workflow that I can create to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!
Cathy

Comment: Cathy, your documents are spread in the site collections and sites right, they are not on a single place? and when you say Publish, it means someone will be manually Publishing the documents or is their a workflow? And what is the extranet location? is it a SharePoint server or ftp folder or any other?